# UNION multiple result sets into separate columns

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, union

I have three SELECT statements that are being returned in multiple result sets:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrdersInStep1 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT        
os.db_OrderNo
FROM tblOrders os
JOIN tblRefOrderType ot on ot.db_OrderType =  os.db_OrderType
LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
WHERE 
    os.db_Deleted = 0 
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND d.db_Task = 1) AS OrdersInStep1

SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrdersInStep2 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT        
os.db_OrderNo
FROM tblOrders os
JOIN tblRefOrderType ot on ot.db_OrderType =  os.db_OrderType   
LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
WHERE 
    os.db_Deleted = 0 
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND d.db_Task = 2) AS OrdersInStep2

SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrdersInStep3 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT        
os.db_OrderNo
FROM tblOrders os
JOIN tblRefOrderType ot on ot.db_OrderType =  os.db_OrderType
LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
WHERE 
    os.db_Deleted = 0 
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND (d.db_Task = 3 OR d.db_Task = 4)
    AND d.db_SeqNo != 34 
    AND d.db_SeqNo != 31) AS OrdersInStep3
```

I can use `UNION` to combine these results sets into one column, but how is it possible to combine them into one result set, but three columns?

Example:

```
OrdersInStep1 | OrdersInStep2 | OrdersInStep3
     12       |      16       |      3
```

Comment: do you have to use those 3 queries?

Comment: No, I could use other queries as long as the conditions and results stay the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can build a CTE that has the orders that you need so you dont have to keep running the same query 3 times.. then just select your counts from the CTE.  A temp table would also be acceptable here instead of CTE and might even perform slightly better..

```
WITH cte AS (
    SELECT 
        os.db_OrderNo,
        d.db_SeqNo,
        d.db_Task
    FROM
        tblOrders os
        JOIN tblRefOrderType ot ON ot.db_OrderType = os.db_OrderType
        JOIN tblDate d ON d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
    WHERE
        os.db_Deleted = 0
        AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01'
        AND d.db_Task IN (1, 2, 3, 4)
)
SELECT
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
      FROM cte 
      WHERE db_Task = 1) OrdersInStep1,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
      FROM cte 
      WHERE db_Task = 2) OrdersInStep2,
    (SELECT COUNT(DISTINCT db_OrderNo) 
      FROM cte 
      WHERE db_Task IN (3, 4) 
        AND db_SeqNo NOT IN (31, 34)) OrdersInStep3
```

Answer (score 1):

You're almost there, you just need to have a matching number of columns in each of your select statements. You can pass empty `''` or `NULL` values as necessary.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) AS OrdersInStep1, NULL as OrdersInStep2, NULL as OrdersInStep3 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT        
os.db_OrderNo
FROM tblOrders os
JOIN tblRefOrderType ot on ot.db_OrderType =  os.db_OrderType
LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
WHERE 
    os.db_Deleted = 0 
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND d.db_Task = 1) AS OrdersInStep1

UNION

SELECT NULL as OrdersInStep1, COUNT(*) AS OrdersInStep2, NULL as OrdersInStep3 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT        
os.db_OrderNo
FROM tblOrders os
JOIN tblRefOrderType ot on ot.db_OrderType =  os.db_OrderType   
LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
WHERE 
    os.db_Deleted = 0 
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND d.db_Task = 2) AS OrdersInStep2

UNION

SELECT NULL as OrdersInStep1, NULL as OrdersInStep2, COUNT(*) AS OrdersInStep3 FROM
(SELECT DISTINCT        
os.db_OrderNo
FROM tblOrders os
JOIN tblRefOrderType ot on ot.db_OrderType =  os.db_OrderType
LEFT JOIN tblDate d on d.db_SeqNo = os.db_Status
WHERE 
    os.db_Deleted = 0 
    AND db_Date39 = '1900/01/01' 
    AND (d.db_Task = 3 OR d.db_Task = 4)
    AND d.db_SeqNo != 34 
    AND d.db_SeqNo != 31) AS OrdersInStep3
```